# How do I get a list of Restricted Friends?

Tags: facebook

I put some friends in my *restricted* list and I would like to get the list of my friends that are in my restricted list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it by pointing your browser to http://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists then *Restricted* or clicking friends on the left on Facebook homepage (you might need to click more).

[image: Friends bookmark]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the url https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking

And then follow the rightmost link of **Restricted List**

[image]